# invalid time when using socket.js with spring boot

Tags: spring, sockets, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to use this project 
[Github project](https://github.com/huseyinbabal/RealtimeChat) and send a message

but when I use it, it gives all message date invalid. but if I refresh the page it set the right messages time what is the problem

Comment: Maybe create an issue on this project's tracker instead of SO?